# How to fix: initialization from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, implicit-conversion

When I compile and run the program, it says: In function 'addToTheEnd': [Warning] initialization from incompatible pointer type //and it points to this line -> knot_t *current = start;

How to fix it? I'm new to C, so I don't understand what should be changed. I tried to understand it but I couldn't. My goal is to get some output out of this program when I run it, but nothing displays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct knot {
    int number;
    struct knot *next;
} knot_t;

int addToTheEnd(knot_t **start, int value) {
    knot_t *new_ = (knot_t *)malloc(sizeof(knot_t));
    if (new_ == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    new_ -> number = value;
    new_ -> next = NULL;
   
    if (start == NULL) {
        *start = new_;
    } else {
        knot_t *current = start;
        while (current -> next != NULL) {
            current = current -> next;
        }
        current -> next = new_;
    }
   
    return 0;
}

void printList(knot_t *start) {
    knot_t *current = start;
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", current->number);
        current = current -> next;
    }
}

void clearList(knot_t *start) {
    knot_t *current = start;
    while (current != NULL) {
        knot_t* trenutni = current;
        current = current -> next;
        free(trenutni);
    }
}

int main() {
    knot_t *start = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(addToTheEnd(&start, i)) {
        printf("Fail\n");
return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
    }
   
    printList(start);
    clearList(start);
   
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `start` has type `knot **` and `current` has type `knot *`. They have incompatible pointer types, which means you are doing something wrong.

Comment: `if (start == NULL) {` --> `if (*start == NULL) {` you want to check if the passed pointer is `NULL`, but instead, you are checking the local pointer (this will always give you `true`)

Comment: @Ian Abbott, So one * is causing the problem, or something else?

Comment: Be aware that `[Warning] initialization from incompatible pointer type` is actually almost always an error rather than a warning.

Comment: It should probably be `knot_t *current = *start;`, since `start` is a pointer to a pointer to `knot_t` coming from `addToTheEnd(&start, i)` in `main()`, and you need to dereference it  to get to the value of `main`'s `start` variable.

Comment: @Ian Abbott, It did fix the problem, but I'm still not getting any output on the screen when I run it.. :(

Comment: Did you fix the `if (start == NULL)` problem too?

Comment: @Ian Abbott I didn't save it before running (oops), so what I saw was outdated output. Yes, It works now.

Comment: @Sas Be aware that your algorithm is correct, but it is very inefficient. The longer the list, the more inefficient it becomes because you need to find the end of the list. Imagine your list has 10000 elements; to add a new element the `while (current -> next != NULL)` loop will run 10000 times. You should maintain the end of the list somewhere, then adding an element of the list will be immediate. Google "schlemiel the painter" ;-)

Comment: @Jabberwocky, Yes, true, and I would never write something like this. But this code was given to me to fix it. So it has to be like this. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function has the parameter `start` of the type `knot_t **`.

```
int addToTheEnd(knot_t **start, int value) {
```

While the local variable `current` has the type `knot_t *`.

```
knot_t *current = start;
```

So as there is no implicit conversion from the type `knot_t **` to the type `knot_t *` the compiler issues an error.

It seems you mean

```
knot_t *current = *start;
```

Also the condition of the if statement

```
 if (start == NULL) {
        *start = new_;
```

must be

```
 if (*start == NULL) {
        *start = new_;
```

Also it would be more logical consistent when the function in the case of success would return 1 instead of 0.

The function can be defined the following way

```
int addToTheEnd( knot_t **start, int value ) 
{
    knot_t *new_knot = malloc( sizeof( knot_t ) );
    int success = new_knot != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_knot -> number = value;
        new_knot -> next = NULL;
   
        while ( *start != NULL ) start = &( *start )->next;

        *start = new_knot;
    } 
   
    return success;
}
```

And as the function `printList` does not change pointed nodes it should be declared at least like

```
void printList( const knot_t *start) {
    const knot_t *current = start;
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", current->number);
        current = current -> next;
    }
```

Comment: Yes @Vlad from Moscow, that's it. Thank you for the detailed answer! Спасибо Владимир :)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
int addToTheEnd(knot_t** start, int value) {
  knot_t* new_ = (knot_t*)malloc(sizeof(knot_t));
  if (new_ == NULL) {
    return 1;
  }
  new_->number = value;
  new_->next = NULL;

  if (*start == NULL) {    // start -> *start
    *start = new_;
  }
  else {
    knot_t* current = *start;    // start -> *start
    while (current->next != NULL) {
      current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = new_;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works, that's what the others were saying as well. Thank you :)